# Разница адресов в C

Tags: c, указатели

Есть следующий код:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 1; int b = 2;
    printf("%d", &a - &b);
    return 0;
}
```

Вопрос 1:
Почему адрес переменной a больше адреса b.

Вопрос 2:
Почему разница адресов равна 3?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment Зависит от настроек компилятора.

Comment: А у меня не равно 3. Что я делаю неправильно?

Comment: А я добился -1 для %d и 4294967295 для %u :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Спешу порадовать, что конструкция `&a - &b` на мой взгляд может отработать как угодно. Если рассуждать логически, то память под переменные a и b выделяется на стеке. Т.е. от старших адресов к младшим. Причем память должна выделяться в порядке объявления переменных. Это и есть ответ на вопрос 1.

Обычно переменные на стеке выделяются подряд, без промежутков. Но тут уж как повезет, т.к. может быть включено выравнивание памяти. И тогда все адреса всех объектов будут кратны каким-то значениям (например, 8 байтам). Более того, у меня лично программа выводит ответ 1. Это означает, что разница в адресах равна одному элементу размера int. А что будет, если компилятор попытается соптимизировать эти инструкции - вообще загадка. И еще попробуйте найти разницу с программой такой:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int a = 1; int b = 2;
   printf("%d", (char*)&a - (char*)&b);                                                                      
   return 0;                                                                                                 
}
```

Прошу обратить внимание, что включение заголовка `stdio.h` необходимо, иначе у компилятора немного крышу может сорвать.

Comment: Использую VS2010. Ваша программа дала ответ 12. Про стековую адресацию я не совсем понял, если не трудно можете объяснить?
Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Стек - это особый способ хранения данных. Наглядно посмотрите на [википедии][1]. Вам нужно знать, что с помощью стека передаются аргументы функций и локальные переменные тоже хранятся в виде стека.

Насчет 12 - это просто. 3 \* sizeof(int) = 3 \* 4 = 12

[1]:http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA

Answer (score 1):

У меня в режиме debug разница 8. В
режиме release 2.

Debug ведь перегружает new delete и возможно какие то низкоуровневые конструкторы для int или что то подобное.

То есть вначале создается  int a;
Потом временная переменная хранящая 1. 
затем b затем переменная для 2.

Comment: Что суть есть конструктор для `int`?

Comment: Ну не конструктор, средства отладки в момент компиляции перехватывают момент создания переменной и дописывают туда код создающий дополнительные переменные, для собственных нужд.

Answer (score 1):

В архитектуре х86 стек растет сверху вниз. Кстати, в архитектуре Spark стек растет наоборот: от меньших адресов в большим, и там будет наблюдаться обратная картина.

Comment: IMHO это больше зависит от компилятора, чем от архитектуры.

gcc.exe (GCC) 3.4.5 (mingw-vista special r3) в 32-bit XP дает 1,  
а gcc.real (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3 *в виртуалке на том же компьютере* -1.

Оба результата не зависят от ключей -O, -g